# Visually midway between two points on a x axis log scale

Tags: matlab, math

The follow plot shows my question:

[image]

I would like to add a line between the points of 1e-1 and 1e-2. So I thought just (1e-1+1e-2)/2.

But for a log scale that is not "midway".

How can I calculate the "visual" midway value between these, or any two points in this case? Code used is

```
clc; clear all;
y = logspace(-3,0,100);
x = y;
semilogx(y,x);
hold on
plot([1e-1 1e-1],get(gca,'YLim'),'k--'); 
plot([1e-2 1e-2],get(gca,'YLim'),'k--');

midway = (1e-1+1e-2)/2;

plot([midway midway],get(gca,'YLim'),'k--');
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [**math.se**](http://math.stackexchange.com/) or on [**dsp.se**](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Geometric mean should do what you want.

Comment: I don't think this question should be closed. It might be answered using math like I did, but there is also the simple programming answer Luis Mendo provided in the comment.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
a=1e-2
b=1e-1
midway = exp((log(a)+log(b))/2)
```

Take the log to get the positions in log scale, then do the math.

You could simplify that formula and you will end up with a geometric mean:

```
midway=sqrt(a*b)
```

Comment: Dude, legend. Thanks. I was trying all sorts of stuff with logspace() haha...

Comment: @SteveHatcher Actually, `logspace(-1, -2, 3)` will give the desired value in the middle